# How to sed the "\\" in variable in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

The following `bash` is used to replace the "`$source_product`" with "`$source_product`" + "`linefeed`" + "`$target_product`".

**Here is the bash script:**

```
source_product="\$(LOCAL_DIR)/source \\"
target_product="\$(LOCAL_DIR)/target \\"

echo "source_product: $source_product"
echo "target_product: $target_product"
echo ""
echo "--- replace source with source+target ---"
echo ""

sed "s|${source_product}|${source_product}\n${target_product}|g" <<< "${source_product}"
```

**Here is the output:**

```
source_product: $(LOCAL_DIR)/source \
target_product: $(LOCAL_DIR)/target \

--- replace source with source+target ---

sed: -e expression #1, char 70: unterminated `s' command
```

**Here is the expected output:**

```
source_product: $(LOCAL_DIR)/source \
target_product: $(LOCAL_DIR)/target \

--- replace source with source+target ---

$(LOCAL_DIR)/source \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/target \
```

What's wrong in the above "`sed`"? And how to fix?

**Update:**

Here is the file contains the "`$(LOCAL_DIR)/source \`", I want to add the "`$(LOCAL_DIR)/target \`" just below the "`$(LOCAL_DIR)/source \`":

```
...
other format a
...
$(LOCAL_DIR)/product_foo \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/bar \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/hello \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/world \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/source \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/others_1 \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/others_2 \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/many_other_products \
...
other format b
...
```

I think `sed` is the best solution.

Comment: You might have a look at [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/3832970). See [this Bash demo](https://ideone.com/3RKygC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes (with more backslashes). You can do this using Bash substitution directly in your `sed` command:

```bash
sed "s|${source_product//\\/\\\\}|${source_product//\\/\\\\}\n${target_product//\\/\\\\}|g" <<< "${source_product}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating this.

Since you *know* exactly what you are passing in, why go to so much trouble to match exactly that and reinsert it back into the string?

```
sed "s,$,\\n$target_product\\,g"   <<< "$source_product" # works
sed "s#.*#&\\n$target_product\\#g" <<< "$source_product" # works
```

(These do need a trailing backslash, added above.)

But more importantly, why use `sed` at all??

```
printf "%s\n%s" "$source_product" "$target_product"
```

`printf` eliminates most of the need for any special processing.

Assuming you mean to *capture* the result -

```
printf -v source_product "%s\n%s" "$source_product" "$target_product"
```

or even just

```
source_product="$source_product
$target_product"
```

or

```
source_product="$source_product"$'\n'"$target_product"
```

TL,DR: Keep It Simple.

## Addendum

> I use sed because the source and target products lines are in a file which contains other products. And then I can use sed -i to replace in a file.

Please *show your use case*. Don't create an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Does this work?

```
$: cat tst
#!/usr/bin/bash
  source_product="\$(LOCAL_DIR)/source\ \\" target_product="\$(LOCAL_DIR)/target\ \\"
  : " \$(LOCAL_DIR)/source \ \$(LOCAL_DIR)/source \ "
  sed "s,$source_product\\,&\\n$target_product\\,g" $0

$: ./tst
#!/usr/bin/bash
  source_product="\$(LOCAL_DIR)/source\ \\" target_product="\$(LOCAL_DIR)/target\ \\"
  : " \$(LOCAL_DIR)/source \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/target \ \$(LOCAL_DIR)/source \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/target \ "
  sed "s,$source_product\\,&\\n$target_product\\,g" $0
```

Comment: I use `sed` because the `source` and `target` products lines are in a file which contains other products. And then I can use `sed -i` to replace in a file.

Comment: Best to mention in the OP.

Comment: @stackbiz neither of the things [you said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77302454/how-to-sed-the-in-variable-in-bash/77304142#comment136281251_77303401) are good reasons to use `sed` instead of `awk` or some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put yourself through escaping hell, just quote your strings, variables, and scripts correctly (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and use a tool like awk that understands literal strings ([sed does not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/3832970)), e.g.:

```
source_product='$(LOCAL_DIR)/source \'
target_product='$(LOCAL_DIR)/target \'

sp="$source_product" tp="$target_product" \
awk '
    BEGIN { sp=ENVIRON["sp"]; tp=ENVIRON["tp"] }
    { print }
    $0 == sp { print tp }
' file
...
other format a
...
$(LOCAL_DIR)/product_foo \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/bar \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/hello \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/world \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/source \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/target \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/others_1 \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/others_2 \
$(LOCAL_DIR)/many_other_products \
...
other format b
...
```

See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) for information on how I'm passing the values of the shell variables to awk as literal strings.

To overwrite the input file with the output, with GNU awk add `-i inplace` just like you use `-i` with GNU sed, or with any command, awk or otherwise, add `> tmp && mv tmp file` to the end of the command.

Comment: Hi, @Ed Morton. I have just added the "`update`" section in my post, how do you replace the target in the provided file use your `awk` solution?

Comment: I thought you were trying to REPLACE source, not add a line below it. That's even simpler. I updated my answer to do that and state how to update the input file.

Comment: No, the original file does not contain the "`$(LOCAL_DIR)/target \\`", I added the "`$(LOCAL_DIR)/target \\`" by using `sed` to replace `source` with "`source + \n + target`". The  "`$(LOCAL_DIR)/target \\`" is new content I want to add it into the file.

Comment: Your script has problem. I have tried to run your script and got the following error:  `...LOCAL_DIR: command not found
bash: /product_foo: No such file or directory...`

Comment: The script doesn't have a problem, you did something wrong copy/pasting it or have put it into a bigger script that has other issues. The script when run as shown in my answer against a file containing the sample input you provided in your question produces the output shown in my answer.

Comment: Regarding [No, the original file does not contain the "$(LOCAL_DIR)/target \`"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77302454/how-to-sed-the-in-variable-in-bash/77304142?noredirect=1#comment136291294_77304142) - I never thought it did, I just thought you were trying to do a replacement rather than add a line. I understand what you want now and my answer does that.